# report builder - show values in single row under column group

Tags: reporting-services

I want to show whether the student has completed the course or not in one single row under course code. But I am getting redundant data. How can I avoid getting redundant data?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If completed appears in the row regardless the order does it mean the student has completed the course? Or what is the logic?

Comment: Yes. When Student has completed a course, Under course code it should appear as "Completed" otherwise "In-progress".  Issue date should be rename As Status.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fixed with using the values “Completed” and “In Progress” back from the data set.

If you were instead to use numbers, such as 1 for Completed and 0 for In Progress the following approach could apply.

Using this dataset

```
Name    TSW_Num    INF_Num    PWD_Num
A       1          0          0
A       0          1          0
A       0          0          1
B       1          0          0
B       0          1          0
```

Would give the following dataset, similar to your displayed in the question

[image]

If you were to create a new table, and set the Row to group on FirstName, and set each of the data cells to be the maximum of the TSW/INF/PWD_Nums, such as

```
=MAX(Fields!TSW_Num.Value)
```

This would result in a design such as this

[image]

Which would render like this

[image]

Now, by wrapping each of those Max(value) expressions in a new expression to convert the value to text, such as

```
=SWITCH(
    MAX(Fields!TSW_Num.Value) = 1, "Completed",
    MAX(Fields!TSW_Num.Value) = 0, "In Progress")
```

Would then, when rendered, result in the following

[image]

Hopefully this is an approach you can apply to solve you existing problem.

You could also potentially use IIF statements to convert your original text values to integer values for performing the MAX calculations on, but that would start to get very messy.

Comment: Thank you Jonnus, I tried this. But the problem is their is only one field, which is "Status" which has value whether student has completed or not. There is no separate status for each and every course. So if the student has followed 3 courses the status come as 3 rows. Is there any solution I can take them in one row? Thank you

Comment: Surely the must be at least e fields, student name, course name and status otherwise where is the other data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the course progress can only have two states Completed and In-Progress as seems in your screenshot, you can use this approach:

I've used this dataset to test my solution:

[image]

I Created a tablix with this data arrangement and row group settings:

[image]

In `Status` column I've set this expression:

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Status.Value,"Student")>1,"Completed","In-Progress")
```

It will preview:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.